# Docker volumes - share file between two containers

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose

I've got a Javascript helper file that contains general functions

Instead of duplicating it to both my containers (Node server and Vue frontend application)
I thought I'll try creating a volume and sharing it between my containers
So I've put it inside a folder called "Shared" in my root directory above my client and server folder which I turn into containers.

file system structure on my local machine:

```
root
--server
--client
--shared
--docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
ENV PORT 8000
EXPOSE $PORT
RUN npm run build
```

Docker-compose.yml file

```
 client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      args:
        NODE_ENV: production
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - type: bind
        source: ./shared
        target: /app/src/shared
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
```

When I go into my container `exec -it container_name bash` and go into the directory i created, I can find the file there ! it was shared and is inside the container

But I cannot access it from my local machine - so I can't actually use it because its not actually created in a way that is useable for me when writing my code
it just sits my in my container - inaccessible

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think you can mount it locally. Afaik you need to copy it in/out of the container. Perhaps someone else knows better?

Comment: thanks for trying to help :) @RaniSharim